# are there any steps available to cross compile gdisk?

Tags: partitioning, gpt, embedded-linux, gdisk

We need `gdisk(from gptdisk)` for am335x based custom board.

We are using Linux OS on the board.

We need to cross compile it. Is there any guide for the same ?

I am not able to find any guide for the same.

Comment: GPT fdisk should not be any different from other tools in terms of cross-compiling. You haven't said what host and target OSes you're using, so it's impossible to really answer your question. I recommend you do a Web search on "cross-compile {host OS} {target OS or CPU}" to find information on this subject.

Comment: @RodSmith Thank you for your attention. We are using Linux on the board. I tried searching online but i couldn't get info on the gdisk cross compilation for ARM.

Comment: As I said, there should be nothing particularly special about `gdisk` on this score. Once you learn about cross-compiling in general, you should either be able to do it or know enough to ask a more specific question.